# Navigation bar - How to keep the page highlighted when selected?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar and when you hover it changes colour (to show the user what will be selected). however, I would like the bar to remain the 'highlighted' color if the user clicks on it so they can see which page they are on (then if they click on a new page it will then highlight that page - basically how do I keep the last page highlighted? 
If you look on this website this is how I want it to work http://www.microsoft.com/web/

Ideally I want to do this through CSS.

Here is HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Hosting</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Domain Names</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Servers</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Support</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
background: #000000;
width: auto;
position: relative;
top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
content:' ';
display: block;
font-size: 0;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 15px 15px;
font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: color .25s;
-moz-transition: color .25s;
-ms-transition: color .25s;
-o-transition: color .25s;
transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
color: #83c9ff;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
content:'';
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: -3px;
top: 19px;
height: 6px;
width: 6px;
background: #ffffff;
opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
content:'';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 3px;
width: 0;
background: #83c9ff;
-webkit-transition: width .25s;
-moz-transition: width .25s;
-ms-transition: width .25s;
-o-transition: width .25s;
transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after, #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
color: #83c9ff;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
    height: 1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .2;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:before, #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:before {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to that with simple jQuery.
I already saw that you added the .active style
just add

```
$("#cssmenu > ul > li").click(function(){
    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

to your document.ready event what this function do, is on every click on li inside #cssmenu it will clear all li from them .active class, then add .active to your requested .li

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/23/

else, if its not same linkmenu just add .active for your each page

Answer (score 0):

Just create an active class and use Jquery to add it and remove it when you click on your links.

**Jquery**

```
   $("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

**CSS**

```
   .active{
        background: Red; //You can add any CSS you like here
    }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/13/)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/25/) using color instead of background. Also, targeting only your `cssmenu` div & links

Answer (score 0):

You can put a:visited or if you can put a class in each of the menu in every page. Like this one for example your currently in HOME page: 
`<li><a href='#' class="visited"><span>Home</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'><span>about</span></a>
  </li>`

Then put a css in the visited class.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about keeping highlighted without page loads, then you can use the below - pure CSS/HTML.

As **King King** notes in the comments however, this may be the only way to implement in only CSS, however does not come without pitfalls.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/15/)

HTML

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' tabindex="1"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' tabindex="2"><span>Hosting</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' tabindex="3"><span>Domain Names</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' tabindex="4"><span>Servers</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' tabindex="5"><span>About Us</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#' tabindex="6"><span>Support</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
 #cssmenu {
    background: #000000;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
    content:' ';
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s;
    -moz-transition: color .25s;
    -ms-transition: color .25s;
    -o-transition: color .25s;
    transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover,#cssmenu ul li a:focus {
    color: #83c9ff;
    outline:0;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before,#cssmenu ul li a:focus:before {
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    top: 19px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #ffffff;
    opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: #83c9ff;
    -webkit-transition: width .25s;
    -moz-transition: width .25s;
    -ms-transition: width .25s;
    -o-transition: width .25s;
    transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after, #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
    color: #83c9ff;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #cssmenu ul li {
        float: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:after {
        display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a:before {
        height: 1px;
        background: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.last > a:before, #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think basing on the `:focus` to style selected tab is a good idea, when any other element gets focus instead, the selected tab won't be style as it should be any more http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/B9CPg/16/

Comment: You're right- I should have noted that this is the only way to do it using only CSS as the OP asked- good note, will ammend

Answer (score 0):

Add this part to your CSS

```
.active {
    color: #83c9ff; 
}
```

then put active clas to your relevent menu items.

eg:- in your hosting page add

```
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Hosting</span></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9CPg/19/